# Swift struct with 'Any' not copied correctly into a function

Tags: swift, struct

Here's my struct -

```
struct SettingsItem {
    var id: String!
    var defaultValue: Any!

    init() {
    }
}
```

Then it's being used -

```
var item2 = SettingsItem()
item2.id = "abcd"
item2.defaultVaule = "1234"
f(item2)             // <-- breakpoint shows a good item
```

When executed, `item` looks good at the breakpoint shown above. But then inside function `f`, `item` is all messed up.

```
func f(item: SettingsItem) {
    println(item)    // <-- bad item!
}
```

It looks like item isn't copied correctly when calling `f`, but when I tried this on a playground it didn't reproduce.

Any ideas for what causes this?

**Update**

It seems to be working well when I change type of `var defaultValue: Any!` to anything else, like `Int!` or `String!`.

Also tried using a default constructor (removed my init()), didn't help.

Why does it fail to copy when using `Any`?

Comment: What does `println(item)` show in `f(_:)`?

Comment: It shows the name of the class. In the debugger's watch it has a member `id = (String!) "\x1a\x05}\f\x01"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode 6.4 I get the same behaviour in a playground too.

Probably best not to rely on the built-in string-conversion functionality as that’s really only for debugging purposes.  Instead, try giving your type an explicit `Printable` implementation:

```
extension SettingsItem: Printable {
    var description: String {
        // make this string whatever you think the appropriate
        // string representation of your value is
        return "{id: \(id), defaultValue: \(defaultValue)}"
    }
}
```

If I add this, it now prints out this way inside `f`.

P.S. I’d suggest thinking about ways you can remove the `!` and `Any` from your struct, they will lead to problems in the longer-term.

Comment: You're right. Printing my struct has shown good data, it's just the debugger's watch that shows bad data.